# Amazon EC2 t1.micro instance

Tags: amazon-ec2

Is there Amazon EC2 t1.micro instance using HVM virtualization?

Currently I'm trying to use it for Apache, Stratos, PHP, Cartridge. But it gives the following error:

> TID: [0] [STRATOS] [2014-08-04 17:25:53,786] ERROR
>   {org.apache.stratos.cloud.controller.impl.CloudControllerServiceImpl}
>   -  Failed to start an instance. MemberContext [memberId=myphp.php.domain38e63a1c-2bc9-4bb3-834e-fe721d6d1864,
>   nodeId=null, clusterId=myphp.php.domain, cartridgeType=php,
>   privateIpAddress=null, publicIpAddress=null, allocatedIpAddress=null,
>   initTime=1407173153551, lbClusterId=lblb-1602734800.lb.domain,
>   networkPartitionId=ec2-region1] Cause: request POST
>   https://ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/ HTTP/1.1 failed with code 400,
>   error: AWSError{requestId='0226e564-6d28-4bc9-8907-41fab944dd45',
>   requestToken='null', code='InvalidParameterCombination',
>   message='Non-Windows instances with a virtualization type of 'hvm' are
>   currently not supported for this instance type.', context='{Response=,
>   Errors=}'}
>   {org.apache.stratos.cloud.controller.impl.CloudControllerServiceImpl}
>       org.jclouds.aws.AWSResponseException: request POST https://ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/ HTTP/1.1 failed with code 400,
>   error: AWSError{requestId='0226e564-6d28-4bc9-8907-41fab944dd45',
>   requestToken='null', code='InvalidParameterCombination',
>   message='Non-Windows instances with a virtualization type of 'hvm' are
>   currently not supported for this instance type.', context='{Response=,
>   Errors=}'}

When I use t2.micro instance it gives this error:

> TID: [0] [STRATOS] [2014-08-05 04:25:59,098] ERROR
>   {org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver} - Unable to
>   build the jclouds object for iaas of type: ec2
>   {org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver}
>   org.apache.stratos.cloud.controller.exception.InvalidIaasProviderException:
>   Unable to build the jclouds object for iaas of type: ec2
>
> Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: hardwareId(t2.micro) not
>   found     at
>   org.jclouds.compute.domain.internal.TemplateBuilderImpl.throwNoSuchElementExceptionAfterLoggingHardwareIds(TemplateBuilderImpl.java:756)
>     at
>   org.jclouds.compute.domain.internal.TemplateBuilderImpl.findHardwareWithId(TemplateBuilderImpl.java:743)
>     at
>   org.jclouds.compute.domain.internal.TemplateBuilderImpl.build(TemplateBuilderImpl.java:694)
>     at
>   org.apache.stratos.cloud.controller.iaases.AWSEC2Iaas.buildTemplate(AWSEC2Iaas.java:121)
>     at
>   org.apache.stratos.cloud.controller.iaases.AWSEC2Iaas.buildComputeServiceAndTemplate(AWSEC2Iaas.java:79)
>     at
>   org.apache.stratos.cloud.controller.util.CloudControllerUtil.setIaas(CloudControllerUtil.java:211)

I doubt it's because of this reason :"[T2 instances must be launched into an Amazon Virtual Private Cloud (VPC); they are not supported on the EC2-Classic platform.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/t2-instances.html)" .

I've searched the web regarding the matter, but still no luck.

If I use m3.medium instead, everything works fine. But it costs.

I would appreciate if somebody gave a clarification on this.

Comment: Whatever program you are using to create your instances is out of date. Get an update from its vendor.

Comment: I've edited the question for the reason I think which causes the problem with t2.micro instance. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, and you _should_ use a VPC. It's free and has a lot of benefits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, t1.micro uses PV instances. Use t2.micro for an HVM instance.